# Mysql: #1064 error in stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, syntax

Whenever I try to create the below stored procedure.

```
   CREATE PROCEDURE purchaseItem (IN productID INT, IN quantity INT, IN price DECIMAL(10,2) , IN memID INT)
    BEGIN
        DECLARE qnty INT DEFAULT 0;
            SELECT p_Unit INTO qnty FROM product WHERE p_ID = productID;
            IF qnty >= quantity && qnty != 0 THEN
                INSERT INTO purchase VALUES (NULL, productID, quantity, price, memID, 0, NULL);
                    UPDATE product SET p_Unit = (qnty - quantity) WHERE p_ID = productID;
            END IF;
    END;
```

I get the error

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3
```

Can someone please point out me where I'm doing wrong.
Thanks!

Comment: What happens if you execute the procedure body line by line - does it work, or do you get the same error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget to change the `DELIMITER`, try the following query without using `SELECT..INTO`

```
   DELIMITER $$
   CREATE PROCEDURE purchaseItem 
    (
      IN productID INT, 
      IN quantity INT, 
      IN price DECIMAL(10,2) , 
      IN memID INT
    )
    BEGIN
            DECLARE qnty INT;
            SET qnty = (SELECT p_Unit FROM product WHERE p_ID = productID);
            IF qnty >= quantity && qnty != 0 THEN
                INSERT INTO purchase VALUES 
                      (NULL, productID, quantity, price, memID, 0, NULL);
                UPDATE product 
                SET p_Unit = (qnty - quantity) 
                WHERE p_ID = productID;
            END IF;
    END$$
    DELIMITER ;
```